# Eclipse: mocking up the platform for testing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, infinitest

I am developing an Eclipse plugin and have tests for it. Some are regular JUnit tests, some are PDE tests (i.e. require starting an eclipse instance to be able to access eclipse internals).

I wonder if it would be a good idea to try to turn some of the PDE test into regular tests, by creating mock objects for the platform. It would be a lot of work, but I think it would save time because the tests will run faster and we will also be able to use  [Infinitest](http://infinitest.org) for more tests.

I would appreciate any feedback, so that I can make up my mind about how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

best regards,
Vlad

Comment: eclipse has tests, maybe you should see how they do it.

Comment: Thanks, that might be a good idea to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a lot of work since you can't reuse much of the original code (which is riddled with lots of `private final static` for runtime data which you can't get rid of nor can you access it).

I suggest to give it a try. If it seems feasible at all, you can implement what you need for your plugin and then hand the result over to the Eclipse community to extend.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. It won't work for everything (for example the jobs framework seems very difficult), but hopefully for enough of it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps:

http://blog.srvme.de/2010/12/10/mock-eclipse-ifile/